# SimpleXML writing in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

First of all i have to tell you that i'm absoluetly new to PHP!

I want to write into a simple XML file.

I have a loop in which if the file does not exists I create the file and add the first child I need:

```
$newFile = simplexml_load_file("myXMLPattern.xml"); 
$UDID = $newFile->addChild('UDID');
$valueUDID = $UDID->addChild('valueUDID',$udidDevice);
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($newFile->asXML());
$dom->saveXML();
$dom->save("./UDID/".$udidReference.".xml");
```

Everything is ok, it creates my file and add the child I need! I use DOM to get a format file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<iPhone>
  <UDID>
    <valueUDID>myValue</valueUDID>
  </UDID>
</iPhone>
```

When the files exists i simply need to add my  and  child I use:

```
$UDIDFile = simplexml_load_file("./UDID/".$udidReference.".xml"); 
$UDID = $UDIDFile->addChild('UDID');
$valueUDID = $UDIDFile->addChild('valueUDID',$udidDevice);
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($UDIDFile->asXML());
$dom->saveXML();
$dom->save("./UDID/".$udidReference.".xml");
```

But the result I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<iPhone>
  <UDID>
    <valueUDID>myValue</valueUDID>
  </UDID>
  </UDID>
    <valueUDID>myNewValue</valueUDID>
</iPhone>
```

This is not what I want! I simply want to add:

```
<UDID>
  <valueUDID>myNewValue</valueUDID>
</UDID>
```

My code simple close the tag `</UDID>`, I do not know how to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your second code shouldn't this line:

```
$valueUDID = $UDIDFile->addChild('valueUDID',$udidDevice);
```

Be this:

```
$valueUDID = $UDID->addChild('valueUDID',$udidDevice);
```

The reason it does not close it, its because you had the wrong variable name causing it to create 2 new elements on the root.

**[Live DEMO.](https://eval.in/47191)**